# UE4 http request loop

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am looping an http request and calling a url asking for json instructions.
I have to loop in order to know the next thing the game should do. It works smooth if i package the game. But while under development and pressing play, the game did continue but output on the viewport is like 10 fps unless I click the game window. It seems like the viewport panel do this on purpose if your keyboard or mouse is  focused on another window and not on the editor.

```
Request = FHttpModule::Get().CreateRequest(); 

Request->OnProcessRequestComplete().BindUObject(this, &ABoxGridActor::OnResponseReceived);
//   //This is the url on which to process the request
Request->SetURL("http://localhost:8092"); 
Request->SetVerb("GET");
Request->SetHeader(TEXT("User-Agent"), "X-UnrealEngine-Agent");
Request->SetHeader("Content-Type", TEXT("application/json"));
//Request->ProcessRequest();

////not timer loop, one time only
GetWorldTimerManager().SetTimer(tmr, this, &ABoxGridActor::RepeatingFunction, 0.2f, true);

void ABoxGridActor::RepeatingFunction()
{
    if (!boolHasPassed)
    {
        boolHasPassed = true;
        Request->ProcessRequest();
        return;
    }

}

void ABoxGridActor::OnResponseReceived(FHttpRequestPtr RequestP, FHttpResponsePtr Response, bool bWasSuccessful)
{
    boolHasPassed = false;

    //codes
}
```

Comment: How is the focus issue or low fps related to your http loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the editor using less resources when game is not in focus by disabling the option:

```
Edit -> Editor Preferences -> General -> Performance -> Use Less CPU when in Background
```

[image]